# Fill a circle with an outline

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-graphics

I need to draw a filled circle, and it needs to have an outline that is a different colour.  Right now I'm doing this by creating two circles, and filling one then stroking the other.

```
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80));
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80));
```

The problem is that the circle looks a little offset and uneven.  Is there a function that allows the simultaneous drawing of a circle with an outline in a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some thickness to the outline by stroking with a larger pen line width.  You may also need to inset the rectangle of by half the width of the pen.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the circle looks a little offset and uneven.

What do you mean by that? Please edit your question to include a screenshot.

Did you turn off anti-aliasing? If so, that may be the cause.

Did you create the context yourself? If so, please edit your question to include the code that does that.

> Is there a function that allows the simultaneous drawing of a circle with an outline in a single line?

You can use `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` to append the ellipse to the context's current path, then use `CGContextDrawPath` with the `kCGPathFillStroke` operation. It should be slightly faster (since the path is only created once), but shouldn't make any other difference, though.